# if copper is heated, does it become negatively charged?

Tags: thermodynamics, electrons

i'm reading "Electronics for inventors" and there's this part where it says that free electrons never escape material due to electrostatic attraction with positive ions, but if heated, electrons are given enough energy to overcome work function and escape material . My question is : if i have a copper rod and i heat it, will it become negatively charged ?

Comment: Yes.  The process of emitting electrons this way is called thermionic emission https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermionic_emission.  This type of emission but not from copper was the basis of operation of thermionic valves which were replaced by the transistor in the 50s and 60s.

Comment: But once the copper _looses electrons_ how could it possibly be _negatively_ charged?

Comment: Yes was the answer to the emission of electrons but as result of losing the electrons the copper would become positive.